# File transfer between two servers, no FTP, no web

Tags: php, perl, bash, ftp

I am looking to automate the transfer of file in a given directory from one server to another server. they are both on the same network, can ping each-other, and even ssh from one to another.

Currently my methodology is sshing into Server A, pull the files down, SSH into Server B and upload them...

I already saw an article [here](http://www.ozzu.com/unix-linux-forum/server-server-transfer-using-ssh-t19442.html), But I wanted to ask you guys **what is the best way to transfer files from server to server, for embedding in a cron-job, or automating.**

Here are my limitations:

- Neither server can have any public web services (no port 80, no apache, nothing *sadface* )
- Neither server can use any sort of FTP connection (although we can ssh)

Thank you all in advance for your help

Comment: rsync is your friend here! that will work over SSH if you create a key on both servers! Check out this article: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=238672

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is already many answers about scp or rsync. For routine "cron based" backup is rsync better.

Reasons:

- rsync copying only files what are not already at the target
- so, usually a bit faster than scp -r
- has a bunch of useful parameters (e.g. what to do with symlinks and etc)
- with some tweaking can act as "OS X" time machine (hardlinking the latest versions)
- you can run rsync over the ssh, or by rsync daemon (but this is need much more config)
- has a --dry-run arg to show what will copy - nice for developemnt/debugging.

for the simple use try:

```
rsync --dry-run -azvv -e ssh remoteuser@remotehost:/remote/path /local/dir
```

one can add --delete for deleting files what are not exists at remote, and soo... man is your friend.

Ps voting to close, because this belong to superuser.

Comment: Thank you for explaining in more detail the advantages. I had known about SCP, but was looking for informative posts like this one, thank you again

Answer (score 8):

if ssh is working between the servers, [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) seems to be what you're looking for. it's as easy as:

```
scp /dir/source.file user@targethost:dir/target.file
```

Comment: rsync *may* work better as it will only transfer the parts of the file that have been updated. Depends whether the entire file is changing or whether it's just parts of it I guess

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job for [SCP (Secure Copy Protocol)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy)

Comment: I read somewhere that this isn't the _best_ way. Got any insight to share?

Answer (score 1):

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scp

Comment: No need to repost this info. Also, going for cheap rep will take away the great feeling of reaching 10k on your own. Edit: No one actually posted rsync in an answer, so it's kind of ok.

Comment: @John Conde & AlexeyKa - Guys, do you really believe than for SO is the best ending as an link-collection to somewhere in the inet? Try add some explanation, something what comes from your experience. You must not be en expert, but adding **only** links from wikipedia is shallow. Im new in SO, so if i'm wrong - appologize me.

Answer (score 0):

Is SMB an option? You could simply cp the files to a shared folder.